# How to add Titles and icons on ToolBar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hi i am very beginner for android and in my app i have created two Activities they are firstActivity,secondActivity

And in both activities i have added Toolbar as like my below images

but main requirement is how can i add titles and images on this both Activities toolbars as like my below first and second activity screens please help me some one

### toolbar.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

### SecondActivity:-

```
  public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Toolbar toolbar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        }
}
```

### firstScreen:-

[image]

### secondscreen:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can customize your Tool bar in layout like this

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#0F6177"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

   <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title"
               android:text="title"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
                android:torightof="@id/title"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_question_mark"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: ok for second activity do i have to create another customized toolbar?

Comment: its on you you can get the title textview in any activity and create a toolbar layout seperately and include the layout in activities

Comment: i mean can i use this tool bar in all other activities with changing titles and icons separately for each activity

Comment: how can i please help me i am very new for android @Rohit heera and just yesterday i came in this technology

Answer (score 0):

```
Create you activities like this


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@mipmap/back" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/pastrecordtitle"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_surveyrecyclerview" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: if u don't mind can is my sample project file please do this modification and i am not understand how can i apply this,please help me Rohit heera

Comment: can i send Rohit heera?

Comment: sure but this time i am busy when i am free i definately do this

Comment: ok ok i will send after do this send that project to this mail ensisinfo102@gmail.com

Comment: please download and please send that file after modified